# Jquery перевести JSON в массив обьектов

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps-api

У меня сейчас такой код

```
var randomMarkers = [
        { title: 'Marker 1', latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(40.371460, 49.840702) },
        { title: 'Marker 2', latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(40.371399, 49.840360) },
        { title: 'Marker 3', latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(40.371120, 49.840371) },
        { title: 'Marker 4', latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(40.371364, 49.840717) },
        { title: 'Marker 5', latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(40.371104, 49.840633) },
        { title: 'Marker 6', latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(40.371356, 49.840550) } 
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < randomMarkers.length; i++) {
    randomMarkers[i].marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: randomMarkers[i].latLng,
      map: map,
      icon: 'ico.png',
      title: randomMarkers[i].title
    });
  }
```

все работает ОК мне сейчас нужно подгрузить эти marker1, marker2 и т.п. из внешнего JSON
делаю так

```
var randomMarkers = [];

$.getJSON( 'api.php', function(data){ 
    randomMarkers.push(data);
});
```

при выводе в консоль показывает их как массив внутри массива . не понимаю почему.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON( 'api.php', function(data){ 
  randomMarkers = data.map(item => ({
    title: item.title,
    latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(item.lat, item.lng)
  }));
});
```

Comment: одно и тоже.
мне надо чтоб он  создал массив без ключей. 

[{ title: 'Marker 1', id: 'id_1', latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(40.37561, 49.842437) },{ title: 'Marker 2', id: 'id_2', latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(40.37340, 49.843999) },{ title: 'Marker 3', id: 'id_3', latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(40.375912, 49.843887) },{ title: 'Marker 4', id: 'id_4', latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(40.375854, 49.842446) },{ title: 'Marker 5', id: 'id_5', latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(40.374448, 49.84933) }]

а он создает массивы внутри массива да и еще с ключами

Comment: @mrentonee Каких ключей? Я ответил на вопрос "почему".